# Как сделать свой livetemplate css webstorm?

Tags: css, webstorm

Вот задачка: w1.15 превратить в width: 1.15px. Как бы я не пытался - не получается.
У них очень ущербная документация насчет методов в livetemplate. Нашел concat() но как он работает?

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам для этого собственный шаблон? По умолчанию `w1.15` + `Tab` превратится в `width: 1.15em;`, в строгом соответствии с [документацией Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/#supplying-values-with-units).
Если значение по умолчанию Вас не устраивает, можно ввести единицу измерения явно - `w1.15px`

Comment: ну я уже задолбался так править :) по сути я так и делаю. Но это не решение. На то он и эммет чтоб я не делал лишних телодвижений

Answer (score 0):

ээх, почему никто не думает своей головой. заходишь в настройки   File>Settings>Editor>LiveTemplates>+ template group>+ livetemplate
в поле 'abbrevation' пишешь w1.15, описание необязательно, в template text пишешь width: 1.15px. там снизу define нажимаешь и ставишь галку на css

Comment: разьясняю. 1.15 это переменная. как создать новый шаблон я знаю. вместо 1.15 можно 7.24 можно 10.99 3.66 -  любое число с сотыми/десятыми. Просто он все дробные числа преобразует к EM а мне нужно к PX. Вы описали правильно. А вот как обходится модалкой Edit variable. что значат в ней методы. в моем случае по логике подходит concat(), но документации к нему нету.

Comment: Почему нет? "concat(expressions...) 
Returns a concatenation of all the strings passed to the function as parameters". вроде все очевидно...

Comment: concat('15', 'px') попробуйте создать переменную с таким методом и оно по итогу не выведет width: 15px